# Getting console.timeEnd() as a number variable in Typescript

Tags: debugging, typescript

Is it possible to get the value of `console.timeEnd()` as a variable in Typescript? I want to use it for debugging purposes but Im testing my application on a phone so i cant see the console outputs.

If not, is there any quick alternative to achieve my goal without importing anything from github?

Answer (score 0):

If you want access to the numbers, you can use [performance.now()](https://www.w3.org/TR/hr-time/#dom-performance-now), which is robust timing for operations.

Example taken from Pro TypeScript, Chapter 7 - Exceptions, Memory, and Performance (with the detail removed to just show the use of `performance.now()`:

```
var testStart = performance.now();

// Some code under test

var testTime = performance.now() - testStart;
```

In particular, performance time offers microsecond precision and isn't affected by computer clock shifts (for example millisecond corrections etc).

> objects with the same time origin MUST be monotonically increasing and not subject to system clock adjustments or system clock skew

This has been available since...

- Chrome 20
- Firefox 15
- IE 10
- Opera 15
- Safari 8

Answer (score 0):

A very easy way is to use performance.now()

```
const t0 = performance.now()
// your code here
const t1 = performance.now()
console.log(`${t1 - t0} milliseconds`)
```